# Delete all debug expressions from Xcode 5.1 Project

Tags: c++, xcode

I accidentally added a debug expression while working with C++ and XCode 5.1, and now every time I try to view the stack of the function I added this expression to, XCode crashes.  I have no idea how to get rid of this expression without clicking on that function, so I'm a bit lost!  I have found references to an Expressions.something file, but that was for XCode 4, and I don't see it anywhere for XCode 5.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "debug expression" do you mean "breakpoint"? If so, can't you simply clear all breakpoints?

Comment: Not a breakpoint, there is a "Debug Area" where you can view local variables, and registers etc.  If you right click it and goto "Add Expression" you can type in custom stuff (I'm not actually sure it's full functionality as I have never really used it).  I accidentally clicked it, added some random garbage expression, and now xcode crashes every time I want to view the local variables for the function I added this expression to.

Comment: And there's no way of removing this expression? No "remove all" option?

Comment: That's what I'm asking :)  I can't find one, and the only way I know to remove it is to click the function which causes xcode to crash!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1) Close Xcode.

2) In Finder, right click on your Xcode project and choose 'Show package contents' then keep navigating in and opening package contents when required to:

**[your_workspace].xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[login_user_name].xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Expressions.xcexplist**

3) Delete the Expressions.xcexplist file.

4) Open Xcode.

You should now have no expressions set for this project.

***Some interesting things to note about this file for editing purposes:***

- It is a plist type structure, hence you can open it as XML / text.
- You can manually remove sections of scoped expressions.
- `<ContextState contextName="GLOBAL">` contains all the global expressions that can cause Xcode slowdown under some circumstances, ie. unconstrained C++ containers (with no explicit size) that must be evaluated in each stack frame context such as `std::list<>`. If you use C++ - you may know the pain of the Xcode UI locking up whilst each debugger step is taken. This is why i sought out this issue in the first place.
- Other `<ContextState>` sections contain the decorated function name containing expressions for that stack frame context.