# How to remove an xcode debug expression/watch causes a failure and xcode shutdown?

Tags: xcode7, lldb

I have an debug/watch that causes xcode to terminate. I am not fast enough to remove it during debug (right click + delete expression) - is there a way in xcode to remove all expressions/watches from a project?

Comment: Excellent answer by [mysticcoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294133/delete-all-debug-expressions-from-xcode-5-1-project). I managed to manually remove the expression.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26248532